# Entity Image not showing up

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, upload, entity

Good Day people! I am troubled with my code please help. After adding an upload feature to my project, the uploaded photo is not showing up. I am certain upload is working since the photo is transferred to the picture directory and the file path is stored to the database. I am using Entity for development also the size of the photos that I uploaded are less than 1MB.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.branchid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.validid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.completeName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.picture)" height="100" width="100" />
            @*<img src="@Url.Content(item.picture)" alt="Alternate Text" />*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<img src="~/Image/couple213129435.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

As you can see I tried using @Url.Content(item.picture) but that is returning a "value cannot be empty or null" error.

I also tried putting file path stored at the database inside an "img" tag to check if the path is not broken and it's not the image is displaying on the browser. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it's working now I just remove the "~" in the path.